# Неверно добавляются объекты в связанные таблицы в БД

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-jpa

Есть две связанные сущности.

Post

```
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String header;
    private String text;
    private Instant createdDate;
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "posts_tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;
}
```

User

```
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String login;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Boolean isActivated;

}
```

HTTP Post запрос для добавления в таблицу Post

```
@PostMapping("/posts")
public ResponseEntity<Post> createPost(@RequestBody Post post) throws URISyntaxException {
    Post result = postRepository.save(post);
    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/post" + result.getId())).body(result);
}
```

При добавлении новой сущности в БД в контроллере вместо прикрепления к объекту Post конкретного User происходит попытка создания такого же пользователя в таблице, из-за чего выбрасываются подобные ошибки

> Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Как мне добавлять User к Post, чтобы при записи в таблицу Post user_id ссылалось на пользователя в таблице User?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Post{
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}

public class User{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]